# what does # character means in JNDI lookup?

Tags: jndi, special-characters, lookup

does any one know that 
"what does '#' character means in JNDI look up?"
like:

```
helloUser = (HelloUser) ctx.lookup("HelloUser#ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser");
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything special.  It's just a convenient delimiter that doesn't require escaping.  Other characters could have been used.  For example, "!" was chosen by the EJB 3.1 specification.